# How to create /delete auth code in CUCM

Tags: .net, cisco, tapi

I have to create / delete Authorization code based on user credit limit to CUCM from my application (developed using .Net & C#).

I can directly create and delete auth codes using call manager auth code options.

but how to achieve from my application.

Thanks and Regards,

Pooja

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AXL interface, which is based on SOAP. You can find information about the AXL interface at http://developer.cisco.com. Select Cisco Unified Administration AXL (AXL) in the dropdown. There is a lot of material there.

To create Authorization code you need to send xml according to below. Be aware that from CUCM version 8.5 the AXL API has changed a bit, and namespaces is very important in the later versions. Also since CUCM's usually use self-signed certificates you might need to override invalid certificates in your code.

I've been programming toward the AXL interface (not in .net or C# though) for many years and it works pretty well.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <addFacInfo xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.5">
      <facInfo xmlns="">
        <name>testcode</name>
        <code>12345</code>
        <authorizationLevel>5</authorizationLevel>
      </facInfo>
    </addFacInfo>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response: (The returned GUID is the GUID of the new fac code in the db, and when a GUID is returned it indicates that it was successful).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:addFacInfoResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.5">
      <return>{60484313-4FD3-FF7A-615D-DFCE1172B799}</return>
    </ns:addFacInfoResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```